# How to use uname -r

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-10.04

Some instructions say to put 'uname -r' into terminal commands. Is this supposed to be automatically converted by the system to something else? It doesn't get converted to anything on my system. uname -r only works by itself but not as a program argument.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a link to these "instructions" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, it says:

```
`uname -r`
```

Make sure you use the right quotes.  A trivial example is:

```
echo `uname -r`
```

Of course, this is just equivalent to:

```
uname -r
```

The backquotes capture the output of the command as a string.  Generally the equivalent:

```
echo $(uname -r)
```

is considered clearer.  It nests correctly, and it's harder to misinterpret.

Comment: It was the quotes.